# How to find 6 digits in a string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

An example string is `"CPLR_DUK10_772989_2"`. I want to pick out `"772989"` specifically. I would imagine using `re.findall` is a good way to go about it, however, I don't have a very good grasp on regular expression so I find myself stumped on this one.

Here is a sample of code that I thought would work, until I looked at the full list of strings, and saw that it definitely doesn't. I suppose I'm looking for some more robustness!

```
for ad in Ads:
    num = ''.join(re.findall(numbers,ad)[1:7])
    ID.append(num)
ID = pd.Series(ID)
```

Other sample strings: `"Teb1_110765"`, `"PAN1_111572_5"`.

Comment: What are the requirements of the string? Is it always the same length? Do you always want the numbers after the 2nd underscore?

Comment: the strings vary in length and it is not necessarily after the second underscore. The only thing stable is that there will be a 6 digit number preceded by an underscore.

Comment: Could there ever be more than 1 block of 6 digits preceded by an underscore?

Comment: no that is the main identifying characteristic

Answer (score 4):

The regex you are looking for is

```
p = re.findall(r'_(\d{6})', ad)
```

This will match a six-digit number preceded by an underscore, and give you a list of all matches (*should there be more than one*)

**Demo:**

```
>>> import re
>>> stringy =  'CPLR_DUK10_772989_2'
>>> re.findall(r'_(\d{6})', stringy)
['772989']
```

Comment: OP says that the digits must be preceded by an underscore, so I think you'd need to modify the regex and then remove the underscore that it captures.

Comment: @BethCrane From the format of his example strings, I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: @BethCrane But I'll add an alternative :P

Comment: His example strings don't include it, but spec is sacred, and all that :P

Comment: @BethCrane Updated to something that works regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

This should append all sets of 6 numbers that follow an underscore

```
for ad in Ads:
    blocks = re.split('_', ad)
    for block in blocks[1:]:
        if len(block) == 6 and block.isdigit(): 
            ID.append(block)
ID = pd.Series(ID)
```

Comment: I've only modified your code sample - I assume you already have your ID and pd vars set up.

Comment: Note the 'blocks[1:] - the first block is before the first underscore, and so even if it is 6 digits we do not capture it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
>>> s="CPLR_DUK10_772989_2"
>>> [x for x in s.split('_') if len(x)==6 and x.isdigit()]
['772989']
```

If your strings are *really long* and you are only looking for one number, you could use intertools like so:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> next(dropwhile(lambda x: not(len(x)==6 and x.isdigit()), s.split('_')))
'772989'
```